# Google Chrome leaving processes live after closing

Tags: 14.04, google-chrome

I've had problems with Google Chrome that when I close it and then re-open it I get the error message the the Profile could not be opened correctly.

I've traced this problem down to the fact that when Google Chrome closes it leaves several processes live in the Process Manager.

If I kill all the left over processes manually once Chrome has been closed then when I re-start chrome it does not give the "profile could not be opened" error message.

Can anyone help with this problem?!

[Screen Print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezELP.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it's taken over 2 months but I've found the issue.

For some reason - probably something wrong in my installation of ubuntu - when I turned syncing off for Passwords this solved the problem and all Chrome processes close correctly after Chrome is closed.

Haven't a clue why but it works.

Answer (score 0):

To stop them, use:

```
killall chrome
```

Then go into Settings, pick Advanced, and near the bottom you will find a switch where you can set it to NOT allow background processes to run when the program exits.