# Google Chrome fails to open profile correctly on Xubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu, google-chrome

On running Google Chrome, then a while later exiting all screens (using the top-right [X]) on each, I notice that the `/opt/google/chrome/chrome` process still persists, along with very many (20+) other sub-processes/threads.

On occasion, while these processes are still running and no Chrome windows are open, executing `/usr/bin/google-chrome %U` via a desktop launcher icon will:

1. Open four Chrome windows in quick succession;
2. Report the following error for each new window:

[image]

If I dismiss all the error messages, close all the Chrome windows, terminate all the Chrome processes, then run the same command again, everything works fine. It is only on occasion when the processes are already running does this occur.

It is unclear to me where to check/set permissions on the profile. Can anyone point me in the right direction to fix or avoid this problem?

**UPDATE**

- [This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/523709/google-chrome-leaving-processes-live-after-closing) suggests the problem lies in the syncing of passwords. I have tried disabling this, but the problem persists.

Comment: Yes, I have tried deleting the entire `~/.cache/google-chrome` directory, and a purge/install of google-chrome, but the problem persists. Also, yes, I have made certain that the configuration option "Continue running background apps when Google Chrome is closed" is unchecked. My Chrome version is also 41.0.2272.89 (64-bit), and I've been experiencing this problem for several versions prior to this.

Comment: Whoops! Perhaps it was only `.cache`. I'll try deleting `.config.` Thanks.

Comment: I've now tried deleting `~/.config/google-chrome` and `~/.cache/google-chrome`, re-installing from scratch, and the problem persists. I am beginning to suspect there is a problem around the fact I am using the sync feature for everything: bookmarks, passwords, etc.

Comment: Good suggestions, thank you... I'll do both and edit the original question.

Comment: Please run `find ~/.config/google-chrome ~/.cache/google-chrome ! \( -readable -writable \) -ls` as regular user and post the result. This will uncover any files related to your Chrome profile, that aren't readable and writable by you.

Comment: @DavidFoerster The result was: .config/google-chrome/SingletonCookie, and .config/google-chrome/SingletonLock -- nothing  out of the ordinary, it seems.

Comment: Yes, those look like session locks, intentionally broken symbolic links or regular files, that are supposed to be empty or written once upon creation and therefore set read-only even for their owner. I would be curious to see their access permissions.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a [bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=465218) in the current build 41.0.2272.x on Linux. What has worked for me is to rename/remove the "Web Data" file in your default profile. ~/.config/google-chrome/Default/ Unfortunately this is a temp fix as a new update will just revert the issue.

Answer (score -3):

I could fix it with using these commands

```
sudo chmod -R 777 ~/.cache/google-chrome ~/.config/google-chrome
```

Comment: -1 Making the Chrome configuration and chache files readable and writeable by everyone and flagging them as executable, doesn't sound like a good idea at all.